# Spark 1.5.1 + Scala 2.10 + Kafka + Cassandra = Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, sbt-assembly, spark-cassandra-connector

I want to connect Kafka + Cassandra to the Spark 1.5.1.

The versions of the libraries:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.5.1",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka_2.10" % "1.5.1",
  "com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.10" % "1.5.0-M2"
)
```

The initialization and use into app:

```
   val sparkConf = new SparkConf(true)
      .setMaster("local[2]")
      .setAppName("KafkaStreamToCassandraApp")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
      .set("spark.cores.max", "1")
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
```

Creates schema into Cassandra like this:

```
  CassandraConnector(sparkConf).withSessionDo { session =>
      session.execute(s"DROP KEYSPACE IF EXISTS kafka_streaming")
      session.execute(s"CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS kafka_streaming WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 }")
      session.execute(s"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kafka_streaming.wordcount (word TEXT PRIMARY KEY, count COUNTER)")
      session.execute(s"TRUNCATE kafka_streaming.wordcount")
    }
```

Also when prepared `jar`, create a few strategies:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "google", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "apache", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("io", "netty", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "codahale", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("META-INF", "io.netty.versions.properties") => MergeStrategy.first
```

I think the issue is connected with

```
  case PathList("com", "google", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
```

Tied to use `MergeStrategy.last`.

Any ideas?

Got exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.isPrimitive()Z
        at com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec.<init>(TypeCodec.java:142)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec.<init>(TypeCodec.java:136)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec$BlobCodec.<init>(TypeCodec.java:609)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec$BlobCodec.<clinit>(TypeCodec.java:606)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.<clinit>(CodecRegistry.java:147)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Configuration$Builder.build(Configuration.java:259)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.getConfiguration(Cluster.java:1135)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:111)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:178)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:1152)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.createCluster(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:85)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:155)
```

Comment: This is your whole code???

Comment: Sorry, extended, could you please check it

Comment: How are you building your app? Are you using the assembly plugin?

Comment: Yes, sbt clean assembly

Comment: It seems like you are using an incompatible version while merging on your com.google path-list.

Comment: Can you provide the imports of your code (or running code) so we can try to reproduce it?

Comment: Added  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "19.0-rc2" manualy. have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error

```
 [error] /home/user/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.10/jars/spark-network-common_2.10-1.5.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Optional.class
 [error] /home/user/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-16.0.1.jar:com/google/common/base/Optional.class
```

It seems the last is the newest one, maybe you can put:

```
case PathList("com", "google", "common", "base", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
```